# 20.04/gnome: keyboard/mouse detected(?) but not working in xorg

Tags: gnome, keyboard, xorg, 20.04, thinkpad

### TL;DR

My keyboard and trackpad work on GNOME Wayland, but not Xorg. Fusuma trackpad gestures still work on Xorg.

---

### Description

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 on my Thinkpad T460, Intel graphics.

I was having the issue seen here, and followed the instructions: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+question/689506.

(I reinstalled Xorg, per instructions linked above, with:

```bsh
sudo apt remove --purge xorg xserver-xorg gnome-session ubuntu-desktop-minimal ubuntu-desktop gdm3 xwayland
sudo autoremove --purge

mv /etc/X11 /etc/X11.bak
mv /usr/share/X11 /usr/share/X11.bak

sudo apt install gnome-session ubuntu-desktop-minimal
sudo apt install --reinstall xkb-data

reboot
```

)

Afterwards, my keyboard and mouse stopped working completely after logging into Gnome with Xorg. Interestingly, I was running `fusuma` and those gestures still worked, even though I couldn't move the mouse.

My keyboard and mouse both work perfectly in Wayland.

---

### Attempted Solutions

- Reinstall `xkb-data`:

  ```bsh
  sudo apt install --reinstall xkb-data`
  ```
- Install and re-install `xserver-org-input-all`:

  ```bsh
  sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all
  ```
- Repeated previous instructions (from the launchpad answers page above):

  ```bsh
  sudo apt remove --purge xorg xserver-xorg gnome-session ubuntu-desktop-minimal ubuntu-desktop gdm3 xwayland
  sudo apt autoremove --purge
  sudo mv /etc/X11 /etc/X11.bak
  sudo mv /usr/share/X11 /usr/share/X11.bak
  sudo apt install gnome-session ubuntu-desktop-minimal
  ```
- Tried removing fwupd, because someone on the internet said that might work:

  ```bsh
  sudo apt remove fwupd
  ```
- Tried reinstalling and reconfiguring xorg server:

  ```bsh
  sudo apt install --reinstall xserver-org
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-org
  ```
- Tried removing `xserver-xorg-video-intel`:

  ```bsh
  sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel
  ```
- Chowned `.Xauthority`:

  ```bsh
  sudo chown : ~/.Xauthority
  ```

8. Tried to update drivers, but none available.

And, of course, I rebooted after each of those attempted fixes.

---

EDIT: Reinstalled synaptics seemed to fix the touchpad! So now the touchpad works, but none of the other input devices.

Consistent with that, it looks like I'm getting driver issues in the xorg log:

```
[  2039.986] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event3)
[  2039.987] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  2039.987] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  2039.987] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/event5)
[  2039.987] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
[  2039.987] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "Default clickpad buttons"
[  2039.987] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
[  2039.987] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so
[  2039.987] (II) Module synaptics: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2039.987]    compiled for 1.20.8, module version = 1.9.1
[  2039.987]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[  2039.987]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[  2039.987] (II) Using input driver 'synaptics' for 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
[  2039.987] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
[  2039.987] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event5"
[  2040.039] (II) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: found clickpad property
[  2040.039] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: x-axis range 1266 - 5677 (res 44)
[  2040.039] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: y-axis range 1093 - 4832 (res 65)
[  2040.039] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: pressure range 0 - 255
[  2040.039] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: finger width range 0 - 15
[  2040.039] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: buttons: left double triple
[  2040.039] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Vendor 0x2 Product 0x7
[  2040.039] (**) Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
[  2040.039] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
[  2040.039] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
[  2040.074] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5/event5"
[  2040.075] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 6)
[  2040.075] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) MinSpeed is now constant deceleration 2.5
[  2040.075] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) MaxSpeed is now 1.75
[  2040.075] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) AccelFactor is now 0.035
[  2040.075] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[  2040.075] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration profile 1
[  2040.075] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[  2040.075] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[  2040.075] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
[  2040.077] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/mouse0)
[  2040.077] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Ignoring device from InputClass "touchpad ignore duplicates"
[  2040.078] (II) config/udev: Adding input device TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint (/dev/input/event13)
[  2040.078] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  2040.078] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  2040.079] (II) config/udev: Adding input device TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint (/dev/input/mouse2)
[  2040.079] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  2040.079] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  2040.087] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ThinkPad Extra Buttons (/dev/input/event15)
[  2040.087] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  2040.087] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
```

That's a lead!

---

### Update: solution!

Ultimately, it looks like the almost-nuclear option worked here--I just removed everything xserver-related and reinstalled:

```bsh
sudo apt-get purge xorg "xserver-*"
sudo apt-get purge lightdm plymouth
sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get install xauth xorg openbox lightdm plymouth
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

After that, things were up and running as usual again.

An answer explaining what happened here would still be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score -1):

Basic on your experience, I tried `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-libinput` to fix my mouse and keyboard not working issue on raspberrypi (lxqt).